# How does AuthenticationMiddleware handle multiple schemes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

we know we can use multiple schemes to authentacate users such as

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options => builder.Configuration.Bind("JwtSettings", options))
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options => builder.Configuration.Bind("CookieSettings", options));
```

but according to the `AuthenticationMiddleware` code:
https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs,50

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    // ...
    var handlers = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationHandlerProvider>();
    foreach (var scheme in await Schemes.GetRequestHandlerSchemesAsync())
    {
        var handler = await handlers.GetHandlerAsync(context, scheme.Name) as IAuthenticationRequestHandler;
        if (handler != null && await handler.HandleRequestAsync())
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    var defaultAuthenticate = await Schemes.GetDefaultAuthenticateSchemeAsync();
    if (defaultAuthenticate != null)
    {
        var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync(defaultAuthenticate.Name);
        // ...
    }

    await _next(context);
}
```

the `foreach`seems to apply mulitple schemes in the first place. However, it uses `IAuthenticationRequestHandler` not `IAuthenticationHandler`.

so when we call `AddCookie` extension method, we add scheme of the handler type to be `CookieAuthenticationHandler` (https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieExtensions.cs,81)
and the interface implementation chain is :

```
public class CookieAuthenticationHandler : SignInAuthenticationHandler<CookieAuthenticationOptions>

public abstract class SignInAuthenticationHandler<TOptions> : SignOutAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>, IAuthenticationSignInHandler

// ...
```

`SignInAuthenticationHandler` doesn't implement `IAuthenticationRequestHandler` if we trace all the way up, so how does `AuthenticationMiddleware` handle multiple schemes and invoke multiple handlers? as far as I can see, only the default scheme is applied?

Comment: ASP.NET Core is... complicated when it comes to supporting multiple schemes: but I think this article should answer your question:  https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme.md (FWIW, `IAuthenticationRequestHandler` is somewhat of a red-herring as it's  (as of ASP.NET Core 5.0) currently only implemented by the handler for HTTP-Negotiate (NTLM, Kerberos, etc) and not any of the stock auth libs (Cookies, JWT, etc).

Comment: ...but basically, (AFAIK) recent versions of ASP.NET Core do not support multiple _default_ authentication schemes - but if you do want to use multiple schemes you can specify them in an AuthenticationPolicy and/or the `[AuthorizeAttribute]`. I'm currently working on an SPA+web-service project where the SPA uses Cookies (as SPAs cannot securely use JWT) so the web-service needs to accept both Cookies _and_ JWT auth on (almost) all endpoints - I've found it helps if I actually remove any Default scheme and require everything to be explicit (via Policy, not `[Authorize]`, that'd be tedious!).

Comment: @Dai ok, can you show me the `AuthenticationMiddleware` source code  https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs which code block calls multiple `IAuthenticationHandler`?

Comment: See my posted answer which answers your follow-up question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** This answer is based on my reading of the ASP.NET Core 7.0.13's assemblies and source code - it does not apply to much earlier versions of ASP.NET Core like 1.x, 2.x, and 3.x (and possibly even 5.x and even 6.x) where the authX system design went through frequent redesigns and iterations.

---

In response to the follow-up question from the OP in a comment:

> ok, can you show me the `AuthenticationMiddleware` source code which code block calls multiple `IAuthenticationHandler`

The answer is "it doesn't" (basically, [the same as what @Kahbazi says in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77472331/159145)), but that then necessarily leads us to ask *"so how does `[Authorize]` work when you specify multiple authentication schemes?"*...

...the answer to that question lies in *another middleware* because (surprisingly), the `AuthenticationMiddleware` is not the only middleware that performs request authentication.

#### Point 1: You'll have an implicit or explicit `AuthorizationPolicy`:

When you have an `[Authorize]` attribute with multiple schemes listed, such as `[Authorize( AuthenticationSchemes = "MyCookieScheme, MyJwtScheme, MyHttpBasicScheme" )]` then ASP.NET will implicitly convert that attribute into an `AuthorizationPolicy` (via `interface IAuthorizeData`) with each scheme listed in that policy's `.AuthenticationSchemes` string collection.

And in the other situation, where you specifically configure an `AuthorizationPolicy` directly (without using `[Authorize]`), then you can set multiple scheme names in `.AuthenticationSchemes` too.

#### Point 2: The `AuthorizationPolicy` is actually evalauted by a different middleware and *not* by `AuthenticationMiddleware`

...instead it's evaluatd by `AuthorizationMiddleware`.

...so **counter-intuitively**, _when you're using 2 or more authentication-schemes then the `AuthorizationMiddleware` will perform double-duty and also authenticate requests in addition to authorizing them.

Right here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ae33890a62edb2fed5554efab597fb7fc41f8cbe/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/AuthorizationMiddleware.cs#L156C9-L156C9

```
public class AuthorizationMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // ...

        var policyEvaluator = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IPolicyEvaluator>();
        var authenticateResult = await policyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(policy, context); // <-- In here

        // ...
    }
```

And the `foreach` loop that iterates over all listed `AuthenticationSchemes` [is in `class PolicyEvaluator : IPolicyEvaluator`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/PolicyEvaluator.cs):

```
foreach (var scheme in policy.AuthenticationSchemes)
{
    var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync(scheme);
    if (result != null && result.Succeeded)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> how does AuthenticationMiddleware handle multiple schemes and invoke multiple handlers?

It won't! As you mentioned `AuthenticationMiddleware` only authenticate the default scheme. If you have multiple authentication scheme you need to use `AuthorizationMiddleware` and `Policy`. You could set what authentication scheme a policy must use and apply that to an endpoint. Then the `AuthorizationMiddleware` would authenticate that endpoint with the specified scheme.